# NodeJS http.request fails when header is too large

Tags: node.js, http, asp.net-web-api

My code is as follows

```
var http = require('http');
var host=...

var postData=({
         //some fun stuff
    })
    var postOptions ={
        host: host,
        path: '/api/dostuff',
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            AppID:"some stuff",
            Authorization: "OAuth token",
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        },
    };

    var req = http.request(postOptions, function(res){
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            //sanitize data stuff here
            console.log("DATA HERE: "+ data);

            return data;
        });
    });
    req.write(JSON.stringify(postData));
    req.end();
```

It's a basic HTTP post to a C# server. The important stuff is in the headers. I send the app ID (which is ~50 characters) and the OAuth token (which can be thousands of characters). Right now, the server isn't set up to do anything with the Authorization header. It doesn't even check if its there.

My problem is that when I populate the Authorization header (or any header) with a few random characters as a test, the post succeeds. When I tried it again with a full valid Authorization token (which, to reiterate, is very long) it fails. No matter which part of the header i fill, once it gets too full it returns an error. The error I receive is "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details". I was somewhat certain this is a server issue, but when I tried running the exact same body and headers in Postman, I got a valid response.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a compiled constant that's defined to be [80k for Node HTTP headers](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/http_parser/http_parser.h#L64). Are you running into that? I'd recommend seeing how big the header is with your OAuth token. It shouldn't exceed 80k though, and FWIW, even a kilobyte is huge for OAuth... But regardless... Try dumping the size of the headers (in bytes).

Comment: I doubt it. The max size of it (I'm using Amazon as my provider) is 2048 bytes according to them. So it's two KB at worst, but well under 80.

Comment: That's what I thought. Second idea... does the OAuth token need escaping? (I haven't worked with OAuth enough to be sure.) Something to try, would be to send your POST request to something like http://requestb.in/ to make sure what you're actually sending, matches the Postman request.

Comment: I tried that. They look exactly the same. This problem is getting a bit rediculous to solve. I'm going to try to use the request module to see If I get better results. The reason I've avoided it is because the testing for this needs to be done on AWS Lambda, so it's annoying to have to rezip a new file on every change rather than just make small changes in their browser editor, but I may have to end up doing it this way.

Comment: Well, its working with the request module. Not my preferred solution, but I guess It was necessary. Thanks anyways for the suggestions.